# PHP - incorrect string length caused by HTML-encoded quote

Tags: php

I have the following string coming from a database: Let's Get Functional

If I run this through strlen it returns 25 characters instead of the expected 20. A var dump shows that the string looks like the above (no html references etc).

If I remove the single quote strlen returns 19 characters.

Obviously the quote is returning 5 characters instead of 1 - why? How can I stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show both of your `var_dump` codes (with results)

Comment: Could you paste the code you use.

Comment: With quote: string(25) "Let's Get Functional"

Comment: Without quote: string(19) "Lets Get Functional"

Comment: Pleas paste the your code here: http://codepad.org/

Comment: It's running from a CMS so not really practical - I could quite easily paste the var_dump($string) but that's not going to be useful. Chances are there's some weird encoding or something happening to the single quote.. pasting the string into stackoverflow or codepad.org and running strlen on it will of course return 20 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @deformhead already explained, it seems that your apostrophe has been converted to the HTML `&apos;` string. My guess would be that between getting the string out of the database and calling strlen() on it you call htmlentities() somewhere in-between.

You can also check how many characters you get from the database in your select query with CHAR_LENGTH() (MySQL).

Another issue you might consider is that strlen() does not work well for multibyte characters so if you'll be working with non-ASCII characters then you'd better use mb_strlen() with the correct encoding. This case however would not explain the difference of 5 characters in your result (strlen() counts the bytes and not characters in a string).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

The `HTML` entity name is `&#39;` for `'`, that equals to 5 chars, so your `strlen()` result is perfectly correct. You don't see HTML references because your browser is *rendering* them. Open the page source to see the actual PHP output.

To avoid this problem you should refrain from using `htmlspecialchars()` function or equivalent encoding on input (as it must be only used upon the output in HTML context).

As a temporary workaround you can apply `html_entity_decode()` before `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be.

```
<?php
$str = "Let's Get Functional";
echo strlen($str), "\n"; // 20
```

[**Look at code output here.**](http://codepad.org/NbNWxqpU)

#### how to debug?

print the ASCII code of each char:

```
$str = "Let's Get Functional";
$len = strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
    echo "$i\t", ord($str[$i]), "\n";
}
```

this is the result:

```
0   L       76
1   e       101
2   t       116
3   '       39
4   s       115
5           32
6   G       71
7   e       101
8   t       116
9           32
10  F       70
11  u       117
12  n       110
13  c       99
14  t       116
15  i       105
16  o       111
17  n       110
18  a       97
19  l       108
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$string = "Let's Get Functional";

echo strlen($string);

?>
```

This code returns 20 characters.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that.. I KNOW it should return 20, but it returns 25 (which I stated in the original question). There's probably some weird encoding or characters getting added by the CMS, and I'm trying to find out the causes so I can eliminate them.

Comment: You never mentioned anything about any CMS in the question. We can only provide answers based on the question you ask. What CMS are you using and where in that CMS is this code? could it be that $string is already set elsewhere? Why not try to see if it works by using another variable. e.g `$myString = "Let's Get Functional";`

Answer (score -1):

I have had same problem as you , may be this will help someone.

The single quote was converted to "& #39;" which was giving me incorrect result.
simply replacing the string with single quote have solved my problem.

$string = "Let's Get Functional"; //string from POST or Database

echo strlen($string); //25

$string = str_replace("'", "'",$string);
echo strlen($string); //20